Retrieve a PHP session or cookie in an API
I have a technical issue with retrieving PHP sessions or PHP cookies in an API call.
I have a file test-cookie2.php:
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["gv_cust_cid4"] = 566;

echo '<br>Sessie: '.$_SESSION["gv_cust_cid4"];
?>

And a file test-cookie3.php:
<?php
$url = 'https://example.com/test-cookie2.php';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content- 
Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

print_r($data);
?>

If i go directly to test-cookie3.php i have my session value.
If i use postman with this test-cookie3.php url, the sessio value is ok;
But if i update my test-cookie2.php file to this:
<?php
session_start();

echo '<br>Sessie: '.$_SESSION["gv_cust_cid4"];
?>

And i set my $_SESSION["gv_cust_cid4"] value on another page in the same domain, in postman the session is empty... Why? How can I solve this?

Cookies and sessions are specific to the client domain. If you run postman from a different domain it doesn't get your cookies.

Is this the literal code you are testing, or is there more bootstrapping code? For instance, I'm not seeing you set those values anywhere. Do you understand that cookies are bound to the request that initiated them, where "request" can be thought of as a specific person's browser. And modern sessions are almost always cookie-based (data is on the server, proof of ownership is in the session cookie), so they fall under the same rules. If there's more code that you aren't showing, the alternative is that your calling code isn't storing cookies, often called the "cookie jar".

I have updated my question to be more specific for this case.

I'm still confused. You have two files, 2 and 3. In file 3 you a curling over to 2 but you are accessing file 3 in your browser. Are you trying to have PHP proxy the user's cookies/session through curl?
